# Adjustment in closing of modal windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a modal window using html , css and JavaScript codes of which are included in snippets

I have included a second modal window by tapping on text in the body of first window
( In short ,2 modal windows are present )

**Now the issue is** 
Whenever i close the second modal window by tapping on the "x" button/tapping outside of modal window **both** the modal window gets closed together

I want it to happen one at a time , like when i close the second modal window by tapping on "x"/tapping outside of window , only the second window should get closed and the first window should remain active in background

As far as i know , this would require 2 changes in the JavaScript codes where closure of windows is defined (both present at the bottom)  , can someone please adjust it accordingly

Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 0.1875em;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625em solid #888;
  width: 97%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375em 1.25em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 9vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25em;
  top: -0.25em;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125em 1em;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 7vw;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6.50vw;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 3.90vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        <p><a href="#myModal2" class="modal-button">Open Second Modal Window by clicking Me</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        <p>Body Text Comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an array of all the open modals.

Whenever a new modal is opened, I push its `id` to the array. Whenever the user wants to close the modal, I close only the modal with the last `id` and `pop`it out of the array.

```js
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].style.display = "none";
          open_modals.pop();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].style.display = "none";
          open_modals.pop();

        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 0.1875em;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625em solid #888;
  width: 97%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375em 1.25em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 9vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25em;
  top: -0.25em;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125em 1em;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 7vw;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6.50vw;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 3.90vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        <p><a href="#myModal2" class="modal-button">Open Second Modal Window by clicking Me</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        <p>Body Text Comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton dude , that's working perfectly.  Although i have last request if you don't mind . While the modal window is opened it has that animation of being sliding from top.   For closing can you implement animation which slides down while closing each window.  Thanks again

Comment: @BadalSingh You can try and start the animation in reverse when closing and modal.

Comment: hello sir. Just need one last help from you.   I have added a bottom sliding Animation for closing the modal window.  But a weird issue has arisen.  If you open both the modals windows together and proceed to close the second one , the first window doesn't gets closed ( first window will get closed normally if second window is not touched ).   Here is the code - https://jsbin.com/kulucosoba/1/edit?output

Answer (score 1):

All the models close when you click the "x" because you loop through them all. I feel like the proper way to do this, is to create an event listener on the parent then close the specific modal.

Replace

```
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].style.display = "none";
          open_modals.pop();
        }
      }
    }
  }

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

With

```
var theParent = document.querySelector("#modalParent");
theParent.addEventListener("click", hideModal, false);

function hideModal(e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget && e.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        var clickedItem = e.target.closest("div.modal");
          clickedItem.style.display = "none";
    }
}

window.onclick = function(e) {hideModal(e)};
```

The only other requirement is to attach the listener to a parent element, in my case I used `#modalParent`.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux2tgvnz/2/) with working example.

Comment: This solution will not work for clicking outside the modal to close it

Comment: @OmriAttiya - OP already has a specific event for that scenario.

Comment: @OmriAttiya yep i just tried it.  It working well for the "x" button at top right.  Although doesn't work on clicking outside of the modal window to close it

Comment: The issue is `e.stopPropagation();`, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @OmriAttiya - It still closes both modals. Your answer works as intended.

Comment: @BadalSingh - I got everything working after some adjustments. Good question though.